Debian 12のPodmanでcgroups-v1をcgroups-v2に切り替えたい
開発環境
ChromeOSのcrostini上のDebian12
やりたいこと・目的
sudo podman system migrate を実行したときに、WARNのメッセージが出現しないようにしたい
以下、WARNのメッセージ
WARN[0000] Using cgroups-v1 which is deprecated in favor of cgroups-v2 with Podman v5 and will be removed in a future version. Set environment variable `PODMAN_IGNORE_CGROUPSV1_WARNING` to hide this warning. 

再現手順

/etc/subuidと/etc/subgid両方に<user-name>:100000:65536を追記する
go 1.23.4をインストールし、PATHを通す
cargo 1.83.0をインストールする
go-md2manをインストールする
netavark 1.13.1をインストールする
netavarkのソースコードのディレクトリの中にenv_loggerをインストールする
libprotoc 29.2-devをインストールする
podman version 5.3.1をインストールする
sudo podman system migrateを実行する


"最新版" という表現は後から見返した時に曖昧になるので、可能な限り具体的なバージョンを記載して置いた方が親切です。 / 単に警告を非表示にするだけなら、メッセージに表示されている通り事前に環境変数を設定しておくか、バージョンに応じた設定変更が必要な気がします。参考: Podman warns about cgroups-v1 being deprecated, but don't provide more info on how to migrate to cgroup v2

「VM によって提供される基礎となるカーネルは置き換えられません。cgroup v2 を有効にするためにカーネル パラメータを変更する必要がある場合でも、それは実行できません。」とあります。
https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/146280238/how-do-i-enable-cgroup-v2-on-crostini?hl=en
